# Firebase functions - interval inside of an interval, to reduce invocations

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions

The costs of using Firebase cloud functions becomes greater when the amount of invocations becomes greater.

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/a99fe3cd8d9fac6f98060441263ef211.png]

I was wondering if that means that I can reduce the cost when I invoke/run a function x amount of times in a function. I've tested this and it turned out that the invocations were reduced.
This is what I mean:

```
exports.functionName = functions.region("europe-west2").pubsub.schedule('every 1 minutes') 
  .onRun((context) => { //counts as invocation
    console.log("Running...")
    var timesRun = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(() => {
      timesRun += 1;
      if(timesRun === 6){
        console.log("Stopping interval...")
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
      console.log("Executing...")
      
      //code... for example fetching json
      
    }, 10000); //doesn't count as invocation
});
```

With this, I can run my code 5 times a minute, while the official invocation is equal to 1.
Is this really more efficient, or am I missing something?

Comment: Isn't this is just a matter of doing the math to compute if your savings on reduced invocations exceeds the additional cost of leaving that function "running" (costing GB-seconds and CPU-seconds) even when it isn't doing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> With this, I can run my code 5 times a minute, while the official invocation is equal to 1. Is this really more efficient, or am I missing something?

With Cloud Functions you pay for both invocation count **and** CPU/memory usage duration. So while your approach reduces the number of invocations, it increases the amount of time you're using the CPU/memory.

Which one comes out cheaper should be a matter of putting the data into the [pricing calculator](https://firebase.google.com/pricing#blaze-calculator).

Note that while the calculator shows only full seconds, you're actually [billed for compute time](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing#compute_time) per 100ms:

> Compute time is measured in 100ms increments, rounded up to the nearest increment. For example, a function executing for 260ms would be billed as 300ms.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#:%7E:text=Function%20execution%20time%20is%20limited,period%20up%20to%209%20minutes.), your function times out after 1 minute, extended to 9 minutes.

Whatever you do into that time, will count as 1 execution time.

if you start interacting with other services like Firestore, those operations are billed separated.